# Trying to find out if chromebook Supervised User hacked device

Tags: security, chromebook

One of the kids has a chromebook, acer c720. I set him up as a supervised user on 9/5/2014, and was able to view browsing history on supervised user dashboard. However the history stopped on 9/11/2014.

I now have the chromebook and am looking at the browsing history. It still says "supervised user" when he is logged in, and that my account can view his browsing history. There is definitely browsing history in here since the 11th, and the machine is definitely connected to our wireless network, so I assume it should be uploading.

I'm wondering, did he hack it somehow? If so, how can I tell?

One interesting thing I found was in Chrome OS > About > More Info. It says the build date was 9/12/2014.

**Update**

To clear up confusion: I can see browser history on the device. I am also supposed to be able to view it from the Supervised User Dashboard at google.com.

I see more history on the device than on the supervisory dashboard (online, from different device).

Comment: Sept. 12, 2014.

Comment: Don't understand; you say it stopped but you also say you can view the history

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. I can view the history since 9/11 on the device, but not at the supervised user dashboard online from a different device.

Comment: Can you disable enable the feature?

Comment: I'm not familiar with chromebooks/chromeOS, but assuming it has a firewall, the first thing that comes to my mind would be to use a firewall setting to block outward data to the address your Supervised User data is sent. This would allow the application to send data, but it would never reach the destination as the firewall would discard it.